# Woocommerce Cart Default Language Not Changing

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, language

Recently I was successful in changing my clients woocommerce default language to Spanish in the cart section and product section and had no issues. Because I didn't understand Spanish i deleted the .mo file in wp-content/language/woocommerce/

Now when i re added it back nothing changes and I've been stuck on this for days not finding any solutions.

Please any help with this!